# If I go to website X, is it possible somehow detect which applications and processes I am running at the moment on my system?

Tags: web-applications

If I go to website X, is it possible somehow detect which applications and processes I am running at the moment on my system, maybe through Java, Flush or any other technology?

Thanks!

Comment: no it's not possible with any technology. only if the browser you use has a vulnerability that the attacker exploits, but not by regular means.

Comment: Sure it is.  It wouldn't be transparent to the user, though.  Your website would basically attempt to install something on the user's machine and they'd have to allow it.